# How can you set up certificates for clients to use in to log into a webpage in comparison to a username and password?

Tags: https, authentication

I've relatively new here and in the website world. I recently saw that some webpages (eg. some banks) use certificates for logging in. An example of what I'm looking for is here - http://poczta.ingbank.pl/ - this is a bank's webmail page where staff (from what I can see) use certificates to log in. This would eliminate clients from having to log in with a username and password.

Any chance anyone would be able to explain to me what this is and how to do this (in simple/newbie terms) please? Your help would be much appreciated.

Thank you :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [certificate for website login](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/16243/certificate-for-website-login)

Comment: Hi Steve, I've taken a look at this article when googling my question. The problem is, some links are outdated (they don't work at all) and I don't understand a single thing not knowing how this all works and being a newbie. Thanks :)

Comment: If you don't understand it, you may need to hire a developer who can implement something for you.